# How can I obtain a lost copy of a UK Visa Refusal Letter from UKBA or concerned authority?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, lost-documents, nepali-citizens

I am a Citizen from Nepal. I applied for a UK student visa [Tier 4 (General) Student] in November 2009 got refused on grounds of poor documentation. I have lost the hard copy of my visa refusal letter sent along with my application. It was the only copy I received. I also didn't receive any emails or soft copy of it.

Now, I am applying to Australia. In which case, both the University and Australian DIBP will ask for past visa refusals and a copy of the refusal letter. However, I happen to have a photo of only the actual comment given by the Entry Clearance Officer stating the reasons of refusal but not of the whole document.

Is there any mean by which I can obtain a copy of the visa refusal letter from the UKBA or a relevant authority?

Note: Nepal only has a consulate (not an embassy) in Kathmandu. The visa applications are/were forwarded through VFS Nepal to the British High Commission, New Delhi, India. From this link (https://www.quora.com/I-have-lost-my-UK-visa-refusal-letter-Can-I-get-a-duplicate-copy-of-it) I found that the UKBA's Authority, to whom the visa application is forwarded, can provide you with a copy of it. I have emailed the British High Commission, New Delhi, India with necessary details 15 days ago. No response yet.

I am pretty sure they handle this, as my passport has been stamped "UK/New Delhi" on refusal.

Or should I directly email the UKBA requesting for the Visa Refusal Letter?

Please suggest if anyone has any knowledge regarding this.

Comment: Are you sure the Australians require a copy of the refusal? A reason should suffice in most cases.

Comment: Apparently YES. The form for GTE approval before Visa Application does ask for "copies of any previous visas, visa refusals or visa cancellation letters" to be included. My consulting agent also suggests its compulsory, otherwise it may weaken my visa approval chances.

Answer (score 4):

You can submit a [Subject Access Request](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration) to request your personal information and data held by UK Visa and Immigration.

The standard waiting period for a response is up to 40 days, but there is also a Fast Track system you may be able to take advantage of - its in the same link above.

Comment: Thank you very much Moo. I enquired the SAR Unit regarding my case through email and I was told that I will need to make a standard subject access request, with a £10 fee to be paid by cheque or postal order or in cash (in case of application from abroad). They cannot accept requests via email or they cannot send my data to me by email. Apparantly, the only way out for me. A lot of time and money to be spent from my part of the world. Appreciate the help though.

Comment: @PoP it makes sense. They told you the procedure and you pretty much have to stick with it on every step.  But there's no guarantee they will send you back the letter with their response.