# I lost my UK visa refusal letter. I want that letter to apply for another country

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I lost my visa refusal letter and I want a copy to apply for a new visa. How can I obtain a new one. I am from Sri Lanka.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I obtain a lost copy of a UK Visa Refusal Letter from UKBA or concerned authority?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101302/how-can-i-obtain-a-lost-copy-of-a-uk-visa-refusal-letter-from-ukba-or-concerned)

Comment: They are asking me to provide a UK postal address which I don't have. I live in Sri Lanka

Comment: Where does it ask you to provide a UK postal address?

Comment: There is an application form.  I have been filling it however, there was a question that asks about my UK postal address. it won't let me skip.

Comment: Provide your postal address
(Required)
We may use this address to send sensitive personal information and important documents such as your biometric residence permit. If we can’t contact you by email, we will use this postal address. We may use this address for correspondence about your application and may use it to contact you about your immigration status after your application has been decided.

You must notify us immediately if your postal address changes. Find out how to update your details here

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of this? Which form exactly are you trying to fill?

Comment: @Leaderboard I have added them to the question. I went ahead with the option of requesting a particular decision letter under specific

Comment: Does the option to enter address manually work (or is this UK-only as well)?

Comment: It is asking for UK address. I have attached the screenshot

Comment: If you don’t have the refusal letter, you may be able to just provide the details that you remember (type of UK visa you applied for, date of refusal, reason given) and explain in your application and/or a covering letter that you have lost the original refusal letter and have been unable to obtain a copy. The important thing is to *disclose* the refusal, if the country you’re applying to wants more information it’s highly likely they can get it quite easily from UK Immigration.

Comment: It seems bizarre that having refused someone a visa they will only send a copy to a UK address.