UK visa refusal letter
I and my spouse were refused a UK tourist visa 2 yrs ago. I have my refusal letter but I misplaced hers and cant seem to find it in my inbox also.
I am not banned since it is'nt mentioned explicitly just refused since I filled the form incorrectly. However I would like to know if me being the primary applicant is not banned so I am guessing my  wife also should not be banned right? Shes a dependent. Plus is there any way to get her refusal letter again?

Highly unlikely your wife received a ban, based on the information in your question. If I were you I would include the full details of your own refusal in your application, and state in your wife’s application that she was refused at the same time as you but you have misplaced her refusal letter. UKVI will know about it anyway, the important thing is that you disclose both refusals. See related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/181047/i-lost-my-uk-visa-refusal-letter-i-want-that-letter-to-apply-for-another-countr

I did some asking around and i was told that if the primary applicant being me wasnt banned then my spouse wouldnt also
